# How do i map through a nested array?

Tags: reactjs

How do i extract until the last sub_data into an array and also get the data from the third sub_data to form another structure?

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Logo",
    "sub_data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Facebook",
            "sub_data": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "People",
                    "sub_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "title": "Gardening",
                        }
                    ],
                },
    ],
}]
```

Example output:
category is from the title of the third sub_data

```
[{
  title: 'Logo',
  id: 2:
  data: [{
    id: 7,
    title: 'Gardening'
    category: 'People'
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = 
[{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Logo",
    "sub_data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Facebook",
            "sub_data": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "title": "People",
                    "sub_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "title": "Gardening",
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
}]
let newArray = [];
let obj = {};
data.forEach(item1 => {
    item1.sub_data.forEach(item2 => {
        item2.sub_data.forEach(item3 => {
            item3.sub_data.forEach(item4 => {
                obj = {
                    title: item1.title,
                    id: item1.id,
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: item4.id,
                            title: item4.title,
                            category: item3.title
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })
        })
        newArray.push(obj)
    })
})

console.log(newArray)
```